# Expected value of absolute value of power of Gaussian

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution

Is there a closed form solution for

$$
\mathbb{E}(|X^p|)
$$

where $X$ is a Gaussian random variable?

Remarks:

- I know that $\mathbb{E}(X^p)$ is just given by the moments of the Gaussian distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments)
- I know that $\mathbb{E}(|X|^p)$ is the $p$-th moment of the folded normal distribution

Comment: Actually, I think I just found the answer: Trivially, $|x^p| = |x|^p$ for all $x$ and $p$ (even and odd). Hence the solution is indeed just the $p$-th moment of the folded Gaussian distribution. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: $$ E(|X|^p) = \sqrt{\frac{2^p}{\pi}}\Gamma(\frac{p+1}2)$$

Comment: @GabrielRomon How to prove this？