# Solve the recurrence relation: $I_p=\sigma^2(p-1)I_{p-2}+\mu I_{p-1}$

Tags: statistics, recurrence-relations, closed-form

$$
I_p=\sigma^2(p-1)I_{p-2}+\mu I_{p-1}
$$
Does $I$ have a close form expression?

This is the recurrence relation satisfied by the $k$-the original moment of a folded normal distribution. See [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3287580/expected-value-of-absolute-value-of-power-of-gaussian).

I don't know what to do because $p$ appears in the recurrence.

Comment: Are you computing $\operatorname{E}(|X|^p)$ with $X \sim \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$? It has a known closed form in terms of ${_1 \hspace {-1px} F_1}$, but it doesn't satisfy your recurrence relation, unless $\mu = 0$.

Comment: @Maxim I know it is not exactly the same, but very close. But could you give a wikipedia link for $ _1F_1$?

Comment: See [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.4340.pdf).